# Can't get "asyncSupported" to work - Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-7

Apologies for the cross posting but I just can't seem to be able to format code snippets properly. (not that it looks massively better in the java.net forum but...)

I am trying to investigate [this][1]

[1]: https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/cant-get-asyncsupported-work issue.

Any insight into what might be happening much appreciated.

Cheers,
Savvas